# MYSQL change tracking with Trigger or Stored Procedure

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, triggers, record

I am looking at implementing either Stored Procedures or Triggers events to track changes made anywhere in the database. I found examples of how to track changes to a specific table using triggers - but not any examples of how to track changes on a broader level - and not any that would allow me to pass in a variable such as the ID of the user who made the change. Ideally - what I want to do is the following:

Create a record in the history table any time a record is updated in the database - regardless of which table it is in - which contains the following information:

- What table the record is in
- The primary key for the record (which is an auto incremented integer)
- The name of the column that was updated
- The new value
- The ID of the user who made the change
- The IP address of user who did the update

I don't mind calling a Stored Procedure manually in the PHP script if need be - I just am hoping there is a way to auto-populate the table name, column name where the change took place!

Comment: :) beware recursion. Don't track changes to your history table in the history table in the history table in th ...

Comment: Very true!  I have the table that holds the tracking records in a separate database for that reason